# webview2 ExecuteScript is getting called before completion of navigate

Tags: c++, webview2

I am trying to understand webview2 wherein I am trying to navigate to a page which expects username & password,
For this I am calling webview2 navigate API, once navigation is completed I need to inject Java script.
But before navigation is completed executescript is getting executed.

```
{
        m_callbacks[CallbackType::NavigationCompleted] = onComplete;
        m_callbacks[CallbackType::NavigationCompletedWithError] = onError;

        HRESULT hr = m_pImpl->m_webView->Navigate(strURL);
        if (hr != S_OK)
        {
            LOG_ERROR(_T("Navigation failed due to unexpected error."));
            return;
        }
    }
```

Above code snippet is for navigate.
Below code snippet is handler for NavigationCompleted:

```
CHECK_FAILURE(m_pImpl->m_webView->add_NavigationCompleted(
        Callback<ICoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventHandler>(
            [this](
                ICoreWebView2*,
                ICoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs* args) -> HRESULT
            {
                m_isNavigating = false;

                CString strLogMessage;
                BOOL success;
                CHECK_FAILURE(args->get_IsSuccess(&success));

                UINT64 nTransactionID;
                args->get_NavigationId(&nTransactionID);

                wil::unique_cotaskmem_string uri;
                m_pImpl->m_webView->get_Source(&uri);

                if (!success)
                {
                    // Failure case
                    COREWEBVIEW2_WEB_ERROR_STATUS webErrorStatus{};
                    CHECK_FAILURE(args->get_WebErrorStatus(&webErrorStatus));
                    strLogMessage.Format(L"Navigation completed for transaction id %llu with error : %d ", nTransactionID, (int)webErrorStatus);
                    LOG_ERROR(strLogMessage);

                    uri = wil::make_cotaskmem_string(L"");
                    
                    if (webErrorStatus == COREWEBVIEW2_WEB_ERROR_STATUS_CONNECTION_ABORTED)
                    {
                        // another requests might be triggered
                        auto callback = m_callbacks[CallbackType::NavigationCompleted];
                        if (callback != nullptr)
                            RunAsync(callback);
                    }
                    else if (webErrorStatus == COREWEBVIEW2_WEB_ERROR_STATUS_UNKNOWN ||
                        (webErrorStatus >= COREWEBVIEW2_WEB_ERROR_STATUS_SERVER_UNREACHABLE && webErrorStatus <= COREWEBVIEW2_WEB_ERROR_STATUS_UNEXPECTED_ERROR))
                    {
                        // Display custom error for errors other than certificate error
                        auto callback = m_callbacks[CallbackType::NavigationCompletedWithError];
                        if (callback != nullptr)
                            RunAsync(callback);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // There is certificate related error 
                        // so displaying the default browser content for certificate error
                        auto callback = m_callbacks[CallbackType::NavigationCompleted];
                        if (callback != nullptr)
                            RunAsync(callback);
                    }
                    return S_OK;
                }

                if (wcscmp(uri.get(), NAVIGATION_URL_ABOUT_BLANK) == 0)
                {
                    uri = wil::make_cotaskmem_string(L"");
                }

                auto callback = m_callbacks[CallbackType::NavigationCompleted];
                if (callback != nullptr)
                    RunAsync(callback);

                strLogMessage.Format(L"Navigation completed successfully for %llu ", nTransactionID);
                LOG_DEBUG(strLogMessage)
                return S_OK;
            }).Get(), &m_navigationCompletedToken));
```

I tried calling ExecuteScript in above handler, its not working.

Can someone please tell me how to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

There are various [Navigation Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/navigation-events) but NavigationCompleted is the final one. If you perform ExecuteScript during your NavigationCompleted handler and you find ExecuteScript is happening too early, I can think of two cases:

1. There is more than one navigation happening and you are seeing NavigationCompleted being raised for a previous navigation. You could try checking the URI of the WebView2 before ExecutingScript to make sure you're on the page you expect. Or validate the NavigationId property on the navigation events match what you expect.
2. Or if NavigationCompleted is only being raised once for the navigation you expect, and ExecuteScript is still too early, you may need to define your own page specific concept of completed. If the page you are on runs script and that's what you need to wait for before the page is ready to run your ExecuteScript, you can try updating the page to run chrome.webview.postMessage('ready') and watch for that in CoreWebView2.WebMessageReceived and in that event handler perform the ExecuteScript.

Comment: I tried to use 2. approach, when getting height of content of WebView2 control, but still getting wrong value, as if the page is not fully initialised at NavigationComplete event ;)